# Regex to separate Numeric from Alpha

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of strings:

```
"10people"
"5cars"
..
```

How would I split this to?

```
['10','people']
['5','cars']
```

It can be any amount of numbers and text.

I'm thinking about writing some sort of regex - however I'm sure there's an easy way to do it in Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> re.findall('(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)', '12fgsdfg234jhfq35rjg')
['12', 'fgsdfg', '234', 'jhfq', '35', 'rjg']
```

Comment: I would probably use \D instead of [a-zA-Z], which would basically split numbers and non-numbers apart. In other words '(\d+|\D+)'

Answer (score 8):

Use the regex `(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)`.

```
import re
a = ["10people", "5cars"]
[re.match('^(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)$', x).groups() for x in a]
```

Result:

```
[('10', 'people'), ('5', 'cars')]
```

Comment: -1: Doesn't work on strings like `"10cars5toys"`. It even throws an exception: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'` trying to do the list comprehension on a non-match.

Comment: @Tim: This is not even specified!

Comment: @Tim: why do you think that it needs to work for such strings? I don't see OP asking for this. I don't see you asking for this. It's not the problem that is being solved!

Comment: The OP writes "It can be any amount of numbers and text". I don't seem to be the only one who has understood it that way. Perhaps the OP could clarify. In the meantime, I'll retract my vote.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> re.findall("\d+|[a-zA-Z]+","10people")
['10', 'people']

>>> re.findall("\d+|[a-zA-Z]+","10people5cars")
['10', 'people', '5', 'cars']
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, a split on `/(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])/i` separates a string that way.

Comment: +1, for the principle of defining split points using lookaround. However, this doesn't work in Python since `re.split()` never splits on empty pattern matches according to the documentation.

Comment: So insert a delimiter, then split on it: `re.sub(r'(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)','!SPLIT_ME!',s).split(r'!SPLIT_ME!')` ;)

Comment: +1 for the general case, even if the OP didn't necessarily need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '10cars'
>>> m = re.match(r'(\d+)([a-z]+)', s)
>>> print m.group(1)
10
>>> print m.group(2)
cars
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me and goes long loops around to avoid regexpes justbecause they are ugly, here is a non-regex approach:

```
data = "5people10cars"

numbers = "".join(ch if ch.isdigit() else "\n" for ch in data).split()
names = "".join(ch if not ch.isdigit() else "\n" for ch in data).split()

final = zip (numbers, names)
```

Comment: Ugh. Regex's are a thing of beauty compared to that! ;-)

Comment: no...this is beautifull...you should have seen me tryign to that in a single pass, which would involve dynamically declaring a class (with type() ) and instantiating it inside the generator expression) - _That_ was too ugly for even me to go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on jsbueno's idea, using str.translate, followed by split:

```
import string

allchars = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(32,256))
digExtractTrans = string.maketrans(allchars, ''.join(ch if ch.isdigit() else ' ' for ch in allchars))
alpExtractTrans = string.maketrans(allchars, ''.join(ch if ch.isalpha() else ' ' for ch in allchars))

data = "5people10cars"
numbers = data.translate(digExtractTrans).split()
names = data.translate(alpExtractTrans).split()
```

You only need to create the translation tables once, then call translate and split as often as you want.