# Separate word Regex Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a bunch of input files in a loop and I am extracting  tag from them. However, I want to separate some of the words. The incoming strings are in the form cs### where ### => is any number from 0-9.  I want the result to be cs ###. The closest answer I found was this, [Regex to separate Numeric from Alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161519/regex-to-seperate-numeric-from-alpha) . But I cannot get this to work, as the string is being predefined (Static) and mine changes.

Found answer:
Nevermind, I found the answer the following sperates alpha-numeric characters and removes any unwanted non-alphanumeric characters so anything like ab5@6$% =>ab 56

```
gsub(/(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])/i, ' ').gsub(/[^0-9a-z ]/i, ' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

If your string is something like

```
str = "cs3232
cs23
cs423"
```

Then you can do something like

```
str.scan(/((cs)(\d{1,10}))/m).collect{|e| e.shift; e }
# [["cs", "3232"], ["cs", "23"], ["cs", "423"]]
```

Comment: What kind of syntax errors? That works for me. `scan` is the right tool for this job.

Comment: `str.scan(/((cs)(\d{1,10}))/m).each{|e| e.shift }` works as well and is shorter